# How to return datetime in Excel when SQL table has only time?

Tags: excel, datetime, informix

I am currently querying against an Informix SQL table that is datetime, however only holds time, such as "07:30:44". I need to be able to pull this data and have the send_time show what the actual time was, and not "0:00:00".

Example:

```
Informix Table Data
--------------------------
| send_date | 02/09/2016 |  --datetime field
--------------------------
| send_time | 07:30:44   |  --datetime field
--------------------------
```

When I query through Excel via Microsoft Query editor, I can see the correct value, "07:30:44" in the preview, however what is returned in my sheet is "0:00:00". Normally I would change the formatting on the cell, however the literal value for the entire column is "12:00:00 AM".

```
Excel pulls/displays
--------------------------
| send_date | 02/09/2016 |  
--------------------------
| send_time | 12:00:00 AM|  --displayed is "0:00:00"
--------------------------
```

I have cast the field as char to see if it would return correctly, and it does! However you can't use parameters/build quick reports with this method.

```
Desired Excel output
    --------------------------
    | send_date | 02/09/2016 | 
    --------------------------
    | send_time | 07:30:44   | 
    --------------------------
```

Is there another way to resolve this? I'd love to give the users an easy way to build queries without having to cast anything.

Comment: Excel doesn't understand time without date particularly well. It's not clear in your question exactly what you want, though: if the `send_date` and `send_time` fields were merged into a single `DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND`, would that help?

Comment: Edited to clarify the result I am looking for. I am unable to modify the tables on the backend, so I am looking to make this work in Excel, if possible. If not, I will have to continue to cast the field as char and do some manipulation within the workbook. Was hoping for a simple fix that I was unaware of!

Comment: Is creating a VIEW to abstract the cast an option?